# 2gis получить изображение карты с помощью js

Tags: javascript, canvas, карты, html2canvas, 2gis-api

Может кто сталкивался, как можно получить "скриншот" div'a с картой? Попробовал через html2canvas однако результат не удовлетворительный.

Код для получения изображения div'a с картой:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Создание карты</title>
        <script src="https://maps.api.2gis.ru/2.0/loader.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        <script>
            DG.then(function() {
                DG.map('map', {
                    center: [54.98, 82.89],
                    zoom: 13
                });

                html2canvas(document.querySelector("#map")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

В итоге, в документ добавляется следующее изображение. Без карты, без меток и т.д

[image: Какое изображение получаю]

А ожидалось следующее:

[image: Ожидаемое]

Comment: Вероятно, надо дождаться, пока загрузятся тайлы карты?

Comment: Хм, а разве выполнение в блоке then не синхронно?

Comment: Зависит от реализации этого конкретного `then`.

Comment: А как можно в данном случае дождаться загрузки тайла?

Comment: Вы сначала проверьте теорию. Попробуйте подождать пару секунд перед съёмкой. Захватит карту – значит, можно искать более точный способ ожидания.

Comment: не сработало, к сожалению.